# Disable row clicking action helperList Prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I have created a helperList and defined the rowActions using addRowAction view, edit and delete. Everything works fine but I have noticed that on clicking the row not the buttons, the action of the first rowAction button i.e. 'view' in this case is performed. How can I disable it such that only the button click performs the action while clicking anywhere else on the table i.e. on the rows does nothing. I am working on prestashop 1.7.

Comment: Did you find the answer? If yes then post answer.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for the issue and found the solution for that, Hope It will help you

If you want to remove the click you have to define it in your field list for each column with `'remove_onclick' => true,`

```
$this->fields_list = [
        'id' => [
            'title'          => $this->l('Id'),
            'type'           => 'text',
            'align'          => 'center',
            'search'         => false,
            'remove_onclick' => true,
        ],
    ];
```

or     `$helper->no_link       = true;` in Helper Form

```
$helper                = new HelperList();
$helper->no_link       = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "$this->list_no_link = true;" in "__construct()" function.

```
public function __construct()
{
    ...
    ...
    $this->list_no_link = true;
}
```